# How can I search in mongodb using an html page with button and using flask with python?

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask

Hi I'm new to both flask and html.
I have a database that contains a collection of documents (representing road routes) that have the following structure:
[image: Document structure]

I would like to be able to query my mongodb via a html page structured like this:
[image: Html page]

Where in the first field I enter (Lat1, Long1) of my position in the second field insert (Lat2, Long2) of my destination and through the search button if it is present in the database print it below on the page otherwise it will tell me "route not present".

My simple and trivial index.html where I create the buttons is as follows:

```html
<body>
 <h1>Choose your route:</h1>
 <form action="/list" method="get" autocomplete="on">
 <td><input type="text" name="key" placeholder="Your Position" size="20" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="key" placeholder="Search Destination" size="20" /></td>
 <td><button type="submit">Search</button></td>
 <button type="Reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>

</form>
</body>
```

While the python code with flash is the following:

```
@app.route("/list")
def lists ():
#Display the all Task
return render_template('index.html',h=heading)

@app.route("/search", methods=['GET'])
def search():
#Searching a Task with various references
Lat1=request.values.get("Lat1")
Long1=request.values.get("Long1")
Lat2=request.values.get("Lat2")
Long=request.values.get("Long2")
refer=request.values.get("refer")
#I make the comparison to understand if the route is present in the 
database.
if(Lat1 == "Lat1" and Long1 == "Long1" and Lat2 == "Lat2" and Long2 == 
"Long2"):
    test_l = tests.find({Lat1:ObjectId(Lat1)})
    test_l = tests.find({Long1:ObjectId(Long1)})
    test_l = tests.find({Lat2:ObjectId(Lat2)})
    test_l = tests.find({Long2:ObjectId(Long2)})
else:
    print("Route not present")
return 
render_template('searchlist.html',tests=test_l,t=title,h=heading)
```

The searchlist.html page I did not know how to structure it.
So my problem is to create the searchlist.html page and change the python code in flask to be able to search.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry for the delay
here's an approach that should work.

```
<body>
<h1>Choose your route:</h1>
<form action="/list" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
<td><input type="text" name="mypos" placeholder="Your Position" size="20" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="yourpos" placeholder="Search Destination" size="20" /></td>
<td><button type="submit">Search</button></td>
<button type="Reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
```

and the python

```
@app.route('/list', methods=['GET','POST'])
def lists():
if request.method == 'POST':
    my_position = request.form['mypos']#form input on initial position
    your_position = request.form['yourpos']#form input on proposed position
    pos = my_position.split(',')#split input into lat and long
    pos1 = your_position.split(',')
    lat1 = pos[0]#lattitude1
    long1 = pos[1]#longtitude 1
    lat2 = pos1[0]
    long2 = pos1[1]
    routes = mongo.db.routes#collection where routes are present
    check_db = routes.find()#check all documents in collection
    #return render_template('searchlist.html', pos=pos, pos1=pos1,lat1=lat1,long1=long1,lat2=lat2,long2=long2)

    for record in check_db:
        if (record['lat1'] == lat1 and record['lat2'] == lat2 and record['long1'] == long1 and record['long2'] == long2):
            return 'route found'
        else:
            return 'sorry route not found'

return render_template('form.html')
```

please contact me for further clarity

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change your input names to unique values, and set your request methods to both get and post.
Use request.form['name'] to recieve user input, pass this as a query to the db and iterate over all values to find a match.
I am currently not with my laptop. But I will post code that does what you want in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However as I wrote before I'm new to both flash and html. I think I understand your suggestions but I can not combine them correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot elvis-chunks at the end I solved the problem with your code.